# Why my vertica cluster doesn't scale well with increase in number of concurrent users?

Tags: database, vertica

I am running a 10 node Vertica testbed, with each node having 256GB of RAM, and 40 cpu core. When I look at the resource utilisation memory/cpu/IO in vertica management console (MC), I do not see any unusual activity in MC.

CASE A: 1 User Test
I ran single user Jmeter JDBC test, looked at system resource, there hardly any resource-utilization (cpu/memory/IO within 20%)

CASE A: 5 User Test
I ran 5 user Jmeter JDBC test, looked at system resource, there hardly any resource-utilization (cpu/memory/IO within 20%)

However, the 5-user test took about 3-times more than single-user test to execute the queries.

NOTE: these being a SELECT QUERY benchmarking, there was no exclusive-locks

despite being above case why is there a huge time difference?

I am looking for the direction to be followed in such scenario, I have done all the basic fact-checking that Vertica documentation is asking us to do (i.e. looking into query_request, dc_allocation_*, resource_acquisition etc. table for finding the casue).

Comment: Compare the query plan execution times for the queries using query_plan_profiles. What paths are taking more time, and what are taking the same amount of time?

Comment: Have you modified the general built in resource pool or added custom resource pools? or is it still out of the box?

Comment: I have tried customizing planned concurrency and max memory parameters of custom created resource pool, but still vertica doesn't scale when no. of concurrent users increases